# Expect five instances to receive once

Tags: ruby, rspec

There are five `ProxyServer` instances in my test database.

I would like to expect that my method calls `blacklist!` once on every one of those five instances.

I have tried these four:

```
expect_any_instance_of(ProxyServer).to receive(:blacklist!).exactly(5).times
# I know, that this is not supposed to work

expect_any_instances_of(ProxyServer).to receive(:blacklist!).exactly(5).times
# undefined method

ProxyServer.all.each do |proxy|
  expect(proxy).to receive(:blacklist!)
end

ProxyServer.count.times do
  expect_any_instance_of(ProxyServer).to receive(:blacklist!)
end
```

They're all wrong. What is right?

Comment: Is it possible for you to simplify the problem using some mock class and a method?

Answer (score 0):

Your second to last approach should work fine. The following example succeeds, for example:

```
class ProxyServer

  @@servers = []

  def initialize
    @@servers << self
  end

  def blacklist!
  end

  def self.all
    @@servers
  end

end

describe 'my test' do
  it 'should call blacklist! on each of the ProxyServer instances' do
    5.times { ProxyServer.new }
    ProxyServer.all.each { |server| expect(server).to receive(:blacklist!) }
    ProxyServer.all.each { |server| server.blacklist!}
  end
end
```